# How can my function argument determine which of several nested functions is returned?

Tags: python-3.x, function, nested-function

I'm working on a hierarchical clustering problem, where several metrics can be used to evaluate clustering quality (Silhouette score, Calinski-Harabasz and Davies-Bouldin indices). 
I have successfully implemented these metrics *individually*, but would like to combine into one function for convenience, `get_metrics`.

For each metric, their functions look like this:

```
get_Sils(min,max, data):
    ....
    return results
```

where `min` and `max` are the number of clusters to evaluate the metric over, and `results` is an array of their values

I am trying to write `get_metrics()` in this form:

```
get_metrics(min, max, data, metric)
```

where the value of `metric` dictates whether get_Sils, get_CalHars or get_DBs is returned.

I have tried using if statements:

```
if metric = 'Sil':
    return get_sils(min, max, data)
elif metric = 'CalHar':
    return get_CalHars(min, max, data)
else metric = 'DB':
    return get_DBs(min, max, data)
```

But this seems like an inefficient way to do it.

I also tried defining each metric function within the get_metrics function:

```
def get_metrics(min, max, data, metric):
    _metric = metric
    def get_sils(min,max,data):
        # how to get_Sil        
        return results
    return _metric
get_metrics(min, max, data, metric='get_sils')
```

But this returns `get_sils`, a string value.

`get_metrics(min, max, data, 'sils')` should return the same value as `get_sils(min,max, data)`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the function itself in the last argument, and call it by the name `metric`

```
<define your functions>
def get_metrics(min, max, date, metric):
    return metric(min, max, date)

get_metrics(min, max, data, get_sils)
```

Functions are objects, and can be passed as arguments.

Comment: Hum... what's the point of the `get_metrics` function then ? The user can as well directly call `get_sils(min, max, data)`

Comment: it allows for things like generator expressions or list comprehensions producing multiple results based on a list of functions presented for evaluation, among other things. However, if the function definitions are hidden from the caller, then naming them with string would be appropriate.

Comment: I know what callbacks are and what to use them for, thanks. What I meant is that in your current example the get_metrics function is nothing but a totally useless level of indirection.

Comment: I don't disagree. Much like the original function in the question. Presumably there's some larger purpose for which that was the minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Well, the original could at least be used to call the effective function by namen which can make sense for ie a command line tool where you want to allow the user to select the algorithm with a command line switch.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical solution for such problems is to use a dict storing functions as values:

```
_METRICS = {}

# helper decorator, cf below
def register(key):
    def _register(func)
        _METRICS[key] = func
        return func
    return _register

@register("sils")
def get_Sils(...):
   # ...

@register("foo")
def get_foo(...)
   # ...

# etc

def get_metrics(min, max, data, funcname):
    func = _METRICS.get(funcname)
    if not func:
        raise ValueError("unknown funcname '{}'".format(funcname))
    return func(min, max, data)
```

Comment: This was what I was trying to go for, thanks! Decorators are a new concept to me so I wasn't aware how to do it. I'll do some more reading into them to understand them.

Comment: You don't need the decorators actually, you could just build the dict manually...